# Register-like PCIe framework for FPGAs?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, pci-e

I'm playing around with a Chinese PCI Express dev board which is based on a Xilinx Virtex-6 365T XC6VLX365T FPGA: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4001072461753.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2fra

The demo code which comes with the board uses the RIFFA framework to perform PCIe tasks. This is fine -- but the interface it presents to the FPGA is a bunch of FIFOs, and it seems to be intended for throwing a lot of data around really quickly.

My use case is more suited to register read/write type access: set some parameters, let the FPGA run the calculations, periodically check for a status flag to set, and read the results. Essentially something like the ISA or PCI bus without DMA.

Is what I want possible on PCI Express? How can I achieve it?